# How do I set this map value to null in JSTL?

Tags: null, hashmap, jstl

In JSTL, I have HashMap as a page variable.  The HashMap maps Strings to more complex Objects.  I would like to set a value to null.  So I'm trying

```
value: ${myMap[myId]} 
<c:set target="myMap" property="${myId}" value="${null}" />
```

I have verified taht the "value:" statement does print something out, however, I get the following JSTL error

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Invalid property in &lt;set&gt;:  "51b21a0410340adf6501db08"
```

Any ideas how to set the particular entry in my map to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
value: ${myMap[myId]} 
<c:set target="myMap" property="${myId}" value="" />
```

and then in later code you can test if it's empty with:

```
<c:if test="${myMap[myId] is empty}">
```

and avoid trying to deal with "null" in JSTL.

The (probably) better option is to remove it from the map entirely:

```
<c:set var="debug" value="${myMap.remove(myId)}"/>
```

Then your empty check will still work and you won't have to tote around null entries in your hashmap.

Comment: I went with a derivative of your answer, whcih was <c:out value="${myMap.remove(myId)}" />.  "var" is not an attbitue of "c:out" and neither is "remove" all by itself a method of java.util.HashMap.

Comment: Ugh, you're of course absolutely correct.   Was trying to do this from memory without using JSTL in a while.   The trick I used was c:set, not c:out (this way you aren't dumping whitespace to the HTML buffer, so it's a little more clean).  I edited the answer.